# Where Dashcode wire the button click handler?

Tags: dashcode

I have created a button click handler on a Button with Dashcode but I can't see anywhere the handler in index.html whereas I can see handlers of slider in that same html.

Where Dashcode wire the button click handler ?

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MakingaWidgetwithDashcode/MakingaWidgetwithDashcode.html) has this:

```
function yourHandler(event) {
     widget.openURL("http://store.apple.com/");
}
```

[image]